# tabbed application with adwhirl using storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, iad

I've tabbed application with `storyboard`. I want to have `adwhirl` below my tabbar. Though I'm customising my `tabbar` after clicking out at any item.I'm not able to change the position of tabbar at initial stage. And I also want my all `tabbarviewcontrollers` are of custom size, so that after inApp purchase the `adwhirl` will be removed and entire `tabbarviewcontoller` will resize again to its original position.Any idea how to achieve this.FYI I want to have `adwhirl` with `iAd` & `adMob`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many researches I found that with Adwhirl this is not possible. This could be only possible if I want my AdMob & iAd at different places. And since I want my both ads at the same place with different time period . I can't achieve this in this way. So I did it in other way. In which I've taken an Extra UIView. Which will be added when I don't want ads. And will be removed when I need it. And instead of adding it below tabbar. I've integrated ads above tabbar. Thus I've fullfilled my requirement with some stitches.

Answer (score 0):

get [Apple's iAdSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) , and look at TabbedBanner and SplitViewBanner .  you'll have to combine some effects from the two.  the SplitViewBanner will show you how to embed another view-controller inside the BannerViewController, nesting viewControllers.  i think the TabBarBanner code puts the ad "above" the tab-bar, but you can see how the tab-bar controller is created on the fly.  if you combine the two concepts, you can probably get what you want.

additionally, while the examples are with these items on the fly, i was able to create a splitViewController in storyboard, and then re-set the rootViewController to be the bannerViewController containing the tabBarController.

might look something like this (again, assuming you've created the tabBarController in storyboard):

```
    UITabBarController* tabBarController = (id)self.window.rootViewController;
    CGRect tabBarViewFrame = TabBarController.view.frame;
        tabBarViewFrame.origin.y -= application.statusBarFrame.size.height;
        tabBarViewFrame.size.height += application.statusBarFrame.size.height;
    tabBarController.view.frame = tabBarViewFrame;

    // get BannerViewController from the SplitViewBanner of iAdSuite ;
    // it should do the work of creating the space for your iAds only when necessary.

    self.bannerViewController
      = [[BannerViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tabBarController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.bannerViewController;
```

Comment: thanks john. But I've never worked with Applie's iAd suite. So,I'll get back to you after checking it.

Comment: iAdSuite is just examples of how to use iAd.h , ADBannerView.h et al.  nothing significant.  sample code so you know how they expect you to do things.

Comment: not familiar with adwhirl.  the only ad setup that i know that works with apple is iAd.

Comment: i looked at adWhirl briefly, no reason to believe you couldn't set up something the same way.

Comment: ok. Thanks for this information.And I know it's bit difficult to implement this like this way. So I'm searching for the other alternatives.